# Color Change in Selection in a browse

Tags: colors, progress-4gl, openedge

How to change color in progress browse when a row is selected mouse click or keyboard arrow keys. i already have the code for change color.. attached in row-display is the following:

```
IF /*CONDITION IS TRUE*/ THEN DO:
    DO viCounter = 1 TO viNumCols:
       ASSIGN vhCurColHdl      = WIDGET-HANDLE(ENTRY(viCounter,vcColHandles))
           vhCurColHdl:BGCOLOR = 0
           vhCurColHdl:fgcolor = 0.
    END.
END.
```

Comment: i also tried "IF BROWSE BROWSE-1:SELECT-FOCUSED-ROW() THEN" condition. did not work in row-display. also tried other event names

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do - if you make the browse "multiple-selection = TRUE" that is a built in function - selected rows will have a different color.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible. See http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P22578 and http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000056499

Comment: Which OpenEdge version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In versions prior to 11.5 (I think, may be 11.4 or 11.3) the selected line in the browse is coloured according to the theme you have selected. You have no control over this programmatically. You can change the theme I suppose. 
In 11.5, as mentioned above, the colour is selected based on the background colour of the browse. Again you have no direct control over the colour selected, although the decision making is pretty clever.